# Brown clustering, graph partitioning, agglomerative clustering - libraries/software

Tags: clustering

I need to do some experimenting with Brown clustering, graph partitioning, agglomerative clustering.

1) Are there Python/Matlab libraries for that? I know sklearn.cluster but it doesn't have algorithms I need.

2) Is it possible to install graphical interface for Cluto on Mac OS?

3) Overall, are there useful tutorials on using Cluto?

4) Other software for clustering that I could learn within a couple of hours?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For graphs I definitely suggest [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) and [igraph](http://igraph.org/) libraries. They support many graph partitioning algorithms.